# How to Show a Tooltip at the Bottom of a Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In some apps, when a user focues on a certain element, a tooltip will float **at the bottom of the page** which displays information about that element.  For example:

[image]

Does anyone know of a good way to achieve this effect (preferably using Angular, although jQuery is also fine)?

Note that I'm NOT looking for the tooltip that hovers nearby the actual element itself, like so:

[image]

Instead, I'm interested in the tooltip that floats at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control you are NOT looking to use is called a popover.  A popover and a tooltip are both tied to an element on the DOM that has to be interacted with to be shown.

If you want to something in between that shows up in a fixed position *on the window*, use something like the angular port of [Toastr](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) and configure it to show up *when* and *where* you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a plugin like the famous [ToastrJS](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) which can position a toast in the middle of the screen.